# Problem with making a piechart in ArcMap , because of <Null> values in attribute table?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology, attribute-table

I have a problem when trying to make a pie chart in ArcMap,

[image: ![enter image description here]

In the middle-right polygon there is no piechart of age groups. I think the reason is that in attribute table, there are some NULL values for this polygon (area)

[image]

The 80 and 90 age category in the piechart is probably the reason that there is no piechart in the  middle right polygon, and because there are NULL values instead of 0 in attribute table. Is there any way to change the NULL to 0, and to make the piecharts complete over the entire map?

Comment: I have just renamed the label in symbology, the field name actually starts with: tot_70_80 etc. its a illusion of the actual name

Comment: The fields calculator provide an easy way to replace null by a 0 value but be careful that you are not corrupting your data (a null value mean no data recorded while a 0 value mean the value is equal to 0, if you are not sure that your null value are equivalent to 0 you shouldn't replace them)

Comment: Is it always the case for other polygons? If there is any NULL valued column, you do not see a pie chart?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to remove the "Null" values and populate a field with "0" is to use the field calculator.

Follow these steps:-

1. In Field Calculator, select the Python parser, and check the Show Codeblock checkbox.
2. In the Pre-Logic Script Code box, use the following code:

[image]

3)Type the following code in the second box, and replace '!Field_Name!' with the field name from the Fields list, as shown below:-

updateValue(!Field_Name!)

Comment: Or instead of bothering with the pre-logic code, just use one-liner expression like:  `'0' if !tot_80_89! is None else !tot_80_89!`.

Comment: Please always provide code as formatted text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the attribute table using the edit tool. Saving the edits should update the values.